# Console application configuration fails to load using `dotnet run`

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm currently making (attempting at least) a simple console application in .net core. The application is a simple console application. Nothing special about it, a small experiment for RabbitMQ.

The .net version (updated just this morning to latest and greatest):

```
dotnet --version
5.0.103
```

Operating system (not sure if useful):

```
macOS Big Sur 11.2.1
```

When I run the application from IDE (in this particular case that is Rider), no problem. Everything as expected in this case.

As I wanted to run the application from the terminal, that is when the following scenario occurred: Application fails to start as it can't create a connection to the localhost.

The command I used

```
dotnet run --project src/RabbitMQ.Publisher/RabbitMQ.Publisher.csproj

...

Unhandled exception. RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)
 ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'hostName')

...
```

Reading a bit of documentation on the [.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) and [dotnet run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) I couldn't find any particular reason on why this would be failing. In past only time when this would happen (in my current experience) was when I forgot to include the `appsettings.json` into the project. First thing I checked.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

The next thing that I checked is the implementation of the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` method, as I thought something changed. Everything seems fine and backward compatible.

The source code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using IHost host = CreateBuilder(args).Build();
    using Publisher? publisher = host.Services.GetService<Publisher>();

    Debug.Assert(publisher != null, nameof(publisher) + " != null");
    
    publisher.BasicPublish(new BasicPayload
    {
        Message = "Test message"
    });
}

private static IHostBuilder CreateBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.Configure<RabbitMQ>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQ").Bind);
            services.AddTransient<IConnectionFactory>(provider =>
            {
                IOptions<RabbitMQ>? options = provider.GetService<IOptions<RabbitMQ>>();
                
                Debug.Assert(options != null, nameof(options) + " != null");
                
                return new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    HostName = options.Value.HostName
                };
            });
            services.AddTransient<Publisher>();
        });
```

The options class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public sealed class RabbitMQ
{
    [Required] public string HostName { get; set; } = default!;

    [Required] public string Queue { get; set; } = default!;
    
    [Required] public bool Durable { get; set; }
}
```

The contents of `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    },
    "RabbitMQ": {
        "HostName": "localhost",
        "Queue": "basic",
        "Durable": false
    }
}
```

The content of the rest of the files is not big of importance.

I also checked out some other similar issues on SO, different blog posts, etc. I guess I missed something, but for the love of application configuration, I can't seem to find it. Is there anything else, that comes to mind, that I could have missed?

As this is an experimental project, my CDO won't allow me to continue before figuring out what is happening :)

Edit:

Latest experiment:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
{
    string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string? directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    builder.AddJsonFile($"{directoryName}/appsettings.json", optional: false);
})
```

seems to "fix" the issue. So, now I am looking into what is actually copied to the output directory. The default option when `CreateDefaultBuilder` is "searching" for `appsettings.json` is that is `optional`. My assumption that this would fail (I can rewrite the application and configure providers manually to prove this hypothesis, tho not worth the time) much earlier, if this was set to `true`.

Will keep you posted on findings :)

Edit #2:

After checking the code of `CreateDefaultBuilder` it all started making sense. In combination `dotnet run --project ./projects/proj1/proj1.csproj` (example from [dotnet run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) documentation page), it will of course fail. As the path where it will "search" for the files is based on the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. I run the command from the root of the repository, then naturally that will not contain the `appsettings.json` file. The project structure:

```
.
├── Example.RabbitMQ.sln
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── src
│   └── RabbitMQ.Publisher
│       ├── Application
│       ├── Models
│       ├── Options
│       ├── Program.cs
│       ├── Properties
│       ├── RabbitMQ.Publisher.csproj
│       ├── appsettings.json
│       ├── bin
│       └── obj
└── test
```

To illustrate this for the future generations :)

As I was running the command in following manner: `dotnet run --project src/RabbitMQ.Publisher/RabbitMQ.Publisher.csproj` then the path where it would "search" for the appsettings is based on that `src` directory. Which, as by the project structure, doesn't have the file at hand :)

Thanks for rubber ducking people, this was a fun experiment. Now back that original experiment to begin with.

Comment: From which folder are you running the `dotnet run` command? Are you sure the appsettings file is there too? What happens if you remove it? Have you tried outputting the config value to the terminal window?

Comment: Hi David, answers in order:
1. From the root of the repository. 
2. appsettings.json is in the project directory.
3. When outputted, config values are `null`.

In meantime, I was experimenting and constructed the path to `appsettings.json` "manually", which seems to "fix" the problem. Now I am trying to understand what is happening and why the "default" way of working.

Comment: What is "base root"? Please give actual examples.

Comment: What is a Publisher? I believe you are wrapping IModel into Publisher class? You should publish messages from IModel which you create from IConnection. Logic is hidden in your wrapper, something is happening there. Also, your rabbit connection classes like IConnectionFactory should be singletons, otherwise, they will be disposing a connection

Comment: @Olegl, it is a wrapper around `IModel`, as you pointed out. Tho I am failing to see how that is related to the configuration being null in this particular case?
The connection failure is a side-effect of the configuration being `null` (which is in Publisher injected using Options pattern). 

Also, the `HostName` that is configured in the code example above, is in the same code. I also have dropped the RabbitMQ, just for easier "experimentation", but the configuration (without experiment in the edit) is still not being loaded.

Comment: After looking into the implementation of the `CreateDefaultBuilder` it all clicked. Well, there is an "issue" in the current documentation of `dotnet run` command. It is not possible to run this command `dotnet run --project ./projects/proj1/proj1.csproj` as in the example. It will fail as, with the combination of `CreateDefaultBuilder` the path will be relative. So it will always fail to find the `appsettings.json` file in the directory. After changing the current directory to the same level of output or actual project, it runs as expected.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidG, it was at the end based on the level where I was running the command. I updated the question with findings and why I was convinced this would work. The documentation makes sense, till you combine 2 different things. It only took me a walk in the cold weather for this to "click" :)